# Which preposition is correct IN or AT?

Tags: prepositions

A: where were you yesterday?
B: I was (in - at - both ) the concert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either will do.

If the respondent played an instrument or sang, she would probably say that she was in the concert.

If the respondent was in the audience or backstage, she would say that she was at the concert.